# What are the resources for researching Facebook Connect implementation best practices?

Tags: facebook

Are there any resources (blog posts, websites, etc) which provide in-depth explanations of functional and technical considerations/requirements when implementing Facebook Connect? I'm looking for documentation other than what Facebook provides.

Answer (score 0):

facebook latest php sdk tutorial to integrate facebook features in your site

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

and

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/